# In Bigquery, compare multiple rows and select the highest value in each column

Tags: google-bigquery

In Bigquery I want to find a way to do a comparison of multiple rows so that I end up with a record containing the highest value in each column.

My data looks like this:

| RowID | int1 | int2 | int3 | int4 | int5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | null | null | 12 | 12 | null |
| 102 | 10 | null | null | 18 | null |
| 103 | null | 10 | null | null | null |
| 104 | null | null | 10 | 10 | null |
| 105 | null | null | null | null | null |

I want to compare these rows to find the highest value in each column:

| int1 | int2 | int3 | int4 | int5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 10 | 12 | 18 | null |

and insert it into a second table.

I could live with doing the comparisons two rows at a time but would prefer not to.  Also, in the actual data are hundreds of columns in each row.

I haven't tried anything yet because I haven't come up with anything to try.  My knowledge of BQ windowing functions is limited and I haven't dealt with most of the less well-known BQ functions.  In other words, it wouldn't surprise me if there were a "simple" solution.

Would appreciate your collective insight into this one -- thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below approach:

```sql
with sample_data as (
  select 101 as RowID, null as int1, null as int2, 12 as int3,12 as int4, null as int5,
  union all select 102 as RowID, 10 as int1, null as int2, null as int3,18 as int4, null as int5,
  union all select 103 as RowID, null as int1, 10 as int2, null as int3,null as int4, null as int5,
  union all select 104 as RowID, null as int1, null as int2, 10 as int3,10 as int4, null as int5,
  union all select 105 as RowID, null as int1, null as int2, null as int3,null as int4, null as int5,
)

select 
  max(int1) as int1,
  max(int2) as int2,
  max(int3) as int3,
  max(int4) as int4,
  max(int5) as int5,
from sample_data
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Ricco D, this looks promising.  We'll implement it tomorrow and let you know how it worked.

Comment: I don't ask many questions here. So I can do better next time, why was my question voted down?

Comment: @DaleMatt it might be because your sample and expected data are images. Usually community members likes it in text format so it is easy to copy and paste.

Comment: Thanks again, Ricco D.  Using a text format never crossed my mind.